# xhttp send username and password to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to grab information from the site `example.com/something.aspx?id=1`, however this page can only be accessed if the user is logged in.

Therefore, I used the following script to login the user, then grab information from the page, however I'm wondering if the script is properly formatted.

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://example.com/login", {username: 'bob', password: '123'}, true);
xhttp.send();
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/something.aspx?id=1', function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

Comment: __NO__, Why are you mixing things with `jQuery` and `JavaScript` ?

Comment: I'm new to this kind of coding - how would I make all the coding one thing, rather than mixed?

Comment: Everyone was new when they started development.. Read the reference material.. Understand it.. And then dive in it...

Comment: I will do. Can I just check that the line of code where I entered the username and password is coded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't mix jQuery and JavaScript. If you are going to do an specific task, it's one way or another. Be consistent with the syntax of your code. Second, the code is fine, but you'll have to make that code synchronous by setting the third parameter of `open()` to false. If you want to keep the same jQuery syntax, turn your `open()` into a `$.post()` and log in. Then, in the callback, you can make the request to your API.

Comment: I'm new to this kind of coding - how would I make all the coding one thing, rather than mixed?

Comment: Edited the answer. Sorry, made a mistake hahaha